# Equivalence class for a relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Consider the equivalence relation on Z ! Z given by (m, n)R(p, q) if and only if mq = np:

(a) Find the equivalence class represented by (2, 5).

(b) Describe the set S of the equivalence classes determined by R.

Until now I didn't get the idea of equivalence classes, how can I solve the above.

Note: It's NOT a homework, I'm just doing some revision and problem solving.

Comment: Hint: try rewriting the equation $mq = np$ using fractions.

Comment: This relation is actually pretty important to constructing the rational numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** The equivalence class represented by $(2,5)$ are all the ordered pairs $(x, y)\in Z$ such that $(2,5)R(x,y)$:

$$(2,5)R(x,y) \Longleftrightarrow 2y = 5x \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x}{y} = \frac{2}{5}$$

Any ordered pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies this equation is thus part of the equivalence class of $(2,5)$.

**(b)** The set $S$ of the equivalences classes of $R$ in $Z$, is given by:

$$S = \{\left [ (a,b) \right ]_R : (a,b) \in Z \}$$

where $[\cdot]_R$ means the equivalence class of $\cdot$ relatively to $R$. That set is a partition of $Z$, since all equivalences classes are disjoint 
$$ (a,b)R(x,y) \Longrightarrow \left [ (a,b) \right ]_R = \left [ (x,y) \right ]_R $$
and the union of all equivalent classes is $Z$ (the domain of $R$ is all ordered pairs of $Z$).